# Getting checked value after using back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following code on a web page:

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){ 
    console.log($("[name='type']:checked").val());
})
</script>

<form>
A <input type="radio" name="type" value="A"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
B <input type="radio" name="type" value="B"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

When I load the page, the output in the console is, naturally, 'undefined'. Let's say I select the 'A' option, click the submit button and then click the browser's back button. The 'A' option is still checked but the console output is also still 'undefined'. That doesn't seem right. Obviously I want the output to be 'A'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need an event listener to listen for user changes

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not sure how a listener will help here. I'm assuming you're talking about something like $("[name='type']").onchange? That will get triggered after I check the 'A' option but it won't get triggered when the back button is clicked.

Comment: you can check if it is checked when the page is loaded as well (for your back button issue)

Comment: @melvin-hagberg's JSFiddle works for me - after submitting, hitting back shows the selected option on the console.  Seems dodgy to be relying on back-button behaviour but still, apparently it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you are importing jQuery before running the script?

When recreating this issue, I got your wished result simply by importing jQuery first.

Working JS-fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/961qgy4f/

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="A"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="B"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
jQuery(function(){ 
    console.log($("[name='type']:checked").val());
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution works. Of course, I'm importing JQuery but I think the problem might be in the version I'm using - 2.2. With 3.6 it works, with 2.2 - it doesn't. The ":checked" property certainly isn't the issue as it works if one of the options is checked by default.